# Obfuscating C++ Shared Library

Tags: obfuscation, c++

I've been asked to help obfuscate a library (written in C++) which will be distributed to clients. I've already discussed why obfuscation is not necessarily a good idea, and seeing as licensing will be integrated into the software many concerns regarding copy protection are moot.

Regardless, I've been asked to research methods anyway. I've looked into header mangling (and the like) as well as HARES, but I fail to find much that I can use for a library (naturally, these things would destroy any form of API rendering the library useless).

What techniques can I apply that would work for libraries? While I would appreciate recommendations for tools (or compiler flags, etc.) that might be helpful I would like to stress that this is not a tool-focused (i.e. closable) question, but rather one focused on applicable techniques.

Comment: Are you obfuscating the source, or the binary?

Comment: It would be distributed as a .so file, but I assume that either would be acceptable, so long as the end result was a library that would be challenging to reverse engineer.

Comment: It's possible this would be better asked at stackoverflow.

Comment: For libraries I would suggest making sure that the exported functions are locked down.  Strip out any symbols that aren't necessary for the API.  If you're trying to protect intellectual property then I would look at DRM techniques.

Comment: I request a clarification on what is meant by the following: (a) "making sure that the exported functions are locked down". (b) "Strip out any symbols that aren't necessary for the API."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't put much energy to doing it very thoroughly, because the reverse engineer is going to win this round.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155131/is-it-important-to-obfuscate-c-application-code

Obfuscating C++ binaries is a bit of a losing battle. It depends on who you are dealing with, but if your reverse engineer is smart enough to use IDA Pro and a couple of plugins, and a good debugger then it shall all be for naught.

**Obfuscation Priorities**

- Where you can give the reverse engineer useless function names.

Honestly, this doesn't help that much, since ultimately your code will have to call some kind of non obfuscated shared library to get anything done. At some point you will use the standard libary, or the STL, or even make a system call.

- Add false pathways to confound static analysis

So that the reverse engineer can have fun with a debugger. Anti-analysis techniques are well known to the reverse engineer, and they can almost be circumvented with a debugger like ollydbg.

- Write debugger foiling code

That reverse engineers love to play with. Again, this is an expected move, and the response is to just to step around the offending code, or to modify away the traps. Anyone with any formal training in RE will blast past this.

- Pack most of my binary into an encryped region which is decryped by a stub just before execution.

Same answer as above. Reverse engineers train for this from day one.

- Keep in mind the reverse engineers are looking for targeted morsals of information - very rarely are they trying to recreate the entire application. Security intensive code, code for license validation, code for home base communication, networking code. These are all prime targets - put your energy into making these thorny places to live.
- Keep in mind that binaries from the largest corporations on the earth are routinely reverse engineered by people in their early 20's.
- Don't leave your debugging symbols in the final binary, as those will definitely help with analysis.
- If you are dedicated to doing this right, also focus on *wasting the engineers time* - time is always against the reverse engineer.

Remember, that any meaningful obfuscation might also cost you the performance gains that justified working in C++ in the first place. There are many zones in the C world (and for that matter the Java world) where meaningful obfuscation just isn't possible. Games for instance, cannot conceal their calls to the OpenGl APIs, nor can they truly prevent engineers from harvesting their shader code.

Also remember that the reverse engineer is watching your code at the *assembly* level most of the time. He'd rather have your function names, but he can live without it if need be. He can see what your program is doing at the most finite level possible. It is only a matter of time before he finds the critical routines.

For your purposes, find a program to mangle function names, make your boss happy, and call it a day. At least at that point, reverse engineering the software will not be *trivial*.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that I'm fighting a losing battle, our aim is just to make it get to the point where it'd be less irksome to just write the software themselves rather than reverse engineer our code.

Comment: Well, in most RE situations the adversary will be just looking to find the secrets that matter - then you have to rewrite the whole thing yourself. If the adversary straight up copies your binaries byte for byte that's not a problem obfuscation can help with. That's why I said concentrate on the secrets you need to protect.

Comment: That's what I meant. Essentially, the library is an algorithm for one wrapper. The exact flow of the algorithm from input to output is what we (read: my client) aims to hide. The other stuff (helper methods and the like) can be left aside

Comment: In that case, go for debugger evasion and encryption, and make sure and add some confusing code pathways into the code. Note that there isn't a good automated tool to do all this like in Java, and you will need to test it yourself against a decompiler and a debugger to ensure its effectiveness.

Answer (score 3):

Well really you have 2 primary vectors that you have to guard against

1. Disassembley
2. Debugging

My favourite method for preventing the first issue is in memory decryption, take parts of your executable code and encrypt it, have it self decrypt in memory while your library is running, you can also checksum parts of the code and compare the checksum against what is loaded in ram ( have the encrypted portions check the decrypter and vice versa )

Another neat trick is to statically link libraries that you use into your executible so they cannot be easily swapped out to try to see what your code is doing.

Now debugging checking interrupt vectors helps, another trick is to check the 'timing' between various portions of code ( for example if more than a couple of milliseconds worth of delay occurs in code that should execute significantly faster than that then it can be assumed that the code is being debugged

Comment: @ahjohnston25 i hand roll mine typically , the basis would be to take your compiled code and drop it into a char array in your application and use function pointers to reference the arrays.. This is one of the methods that viruses used to hide decades ago ( self encrypting with random keys every time they replicated )